# Using javascript for dynamic images in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

For my laravel website, I have a nav and an image container.

The image inside of the container changes based on which nav item you mouseover.

```
   $(".ddNavItem a, .tier1Nav2").mouseenter(function(){
        itemID = $(this).attr('id');
        newImg = "<img src='images/nav/" + itemID + ".png' >";
        $(".dropImg").html(newImg);
   });
```

Now this was working just fine until I switched my website over to laravel. My nav now only works in website's root public directory.

So I tried using the asset tag.

```
    $(".ddNavItem a, .tier1Nav2").mouseenter(function(){
        itemID = $(this).attr('id');
        newImg = "<img src='{{ asset('images/nav/" + itemID + ".png') }}' >";
        $(".dropImg").html(newImg);
   });
```

This didn't work. The path came out as

```
http://localhost/mysite/public/images/nav/" + itemID + ".png
```

Been stuck on this for a few hours and I was wondering if anyone could help out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm confused, you say it only works in the website's `root public` directory, which is it? The root, or the public? Your assets should be inside of `/public/images/nav/` and when you request then, it's just `/images/nav/image`

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused with laravel is all. It only works on the front page. So, /public/. If I were to go to /public/about/, for example, it would stop working, as it would look for "public/about/images/nav/", which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with how you're mapping your domain's webroot. Laravel is not like Wordpress where you can just install everything in the webroot. You need to make sure that the base directory of your domain is set to something like the following: `/var/www/html/your-laravel-project/public`. If you're on Apache or NGINX, you can check your virtual hosts. If you're on a shared server, check your host's cPanel, Plesk, or other Web GUI tool to make sure you're set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in comments and chat here is what the solution seems to be.

```
<img src='images/nav/"
```

can be changed to

```
<img src='/images/nav/"
```

in

```
$(".ddNavItem a, .tier1Nav2").mouseenter(function(){
    itemID = $(this).attr('id');
    newImg = "<img src='images/nav/" + itemID + ".png' >";
    $(".dropImg").html(newImg);
});
```

The root folder in XAMPP (local environment) needs to be changed to `public` folder within the Laravel installation folder so images can be accessed in

```
http://localhost/images/nav/
```

While on the hard drive they are located in

```
/LaravelInstallationFolder/public/images/nav
```

Comment: The first code only works without the slash befores "images". And images is already in Laravel's public folder.
For both your answers I get the error "ErrorException in 425c2e9f08f0e786b24611a72ab4fa89 line 3: Use of undefined constant itemID - assumed 'itemID' "

Comment: try changing `itemID` into `$itemID` everywhere in your script and see if the error is the same

Comment: Error is the same. Tried $itemID for both.

Comment: keep them `$itemID` and try `newImg = "<img src='{{ asset('images/nav/' . itemID . '.png') }}' >";` Because what is inside {{ }} is actually PHP code and concatenation with + should not work

Comment: The error is still the same. The only difference being that the error message is "Undefined variable: itemID" when using the dollar sign, and "Use of undefined constant itemID - assumed 'itemID'" when not using it.

Comment: It should definitely be a variable. Did you change `itemID = $(this).attr('id');` into `$itemID = $(this).attr('id');`?

Comment: Yes. This is how it looks now: http://pastebin.com/FnPw74WE 
The error is the same regardless of the dollar sign on either "itemID".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117370/discussion-between-felix-maxime-and-arthur-tarasov).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this; `newImg = "<img src='{{ asset('images/nav/" + itemID + ".png') }}' >";` to this; `newImg = "<img src='{{ asset('images/nav/') }} + itemID + \".png\"' >";`.

This should produce the correct HTML img tag for you.

As a whole it is like this:

```
$(".ddNavItem a, .tier1Nav2").mouseenter(function(){
    itemID = $(this).attr('id');
    newImg = "<img src='{{ asset('images/nav/') }} + itemID + \".png\"' >";
    $(".dropImg").html(newImg);
});
```

This should produce:

`http://localhost/mysite/public/images/nav/{id}.png`

Comment: The above is untested, so let me know if you run in to trouble.

Comment: Nope. Image path comes out as public/images/nav + itemID + ".png" when using View Image

Comment: Try storing the image tag as a variable and then including it. Something like `var imgStart = "img src='{{ asset('images/nav/') }}"` and `var imgEnd = ".png"` and then doing `newImg = "\"" + imgStart + itemID + imgEnd + \";`